# Python converting DXF files to WMF

Tags: python, dxf, wmf

Does anyone know any way of converting DXF files to WMF in Python ?

I need to print out a lot of DXF files with a dot matrix printer and I find the best result is to convert DXF to WMF.

I tried to use PNG and PDF but the result is not good enough because the line or circle is not smooth when using PNG or PDF.
That is why I need WMF, thank you.

Comment: High resolution in png file means more storage space. I have several thousands dxf files and still producing more and more dxf files. I have tried a same dxf file converting to png file with resolution 7891x20000, 598KB and wmf file with resolution  8797x4214, 3KB only.

Comment: Thank you very much, K J. Is it ok converting my dxf to svg, and then convert svg to pdf and print out? Could you please tell me something about converting dxf to svg in Python ?